# Как вывести Title страницы на которой сейчас находимся?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, оптимизация-сайтов

Плагин Remove_Redundant_Links удаляет циклические ссылки (cсылки на логотип, например), но после удаления оставляет статическое название 'You are here.'. Как реализовать, чтобы подтягивался title - название страницы вместо статических слов 'You are here.'? Сайт https://nenws.com/

```
    define( 'PLUGIN_RRL_TEXT_DOMAIN', 'plugin-rrl' );
load_plugin_textdomain(
    PLUGIN_RRL_TEXT_DOMAIN
,   FALSE
,   basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/lang'
);

/**
 * Manager for the plugin Remove Redundant Links.
 *
 * @return void
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'rrl_start' ) )
{
    function rrl_start()
    {
        if ( is_feed() )
        {
            return;
        }

        ! class_exists( 'Remove_Redundant_Links' ) and
            include dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/class.Remove_Redundant_Links.php';

        // Make it global to allow easier deactivation.
        global $Remove_Redundant_Links;

        $settings = array (
            'class'   => 'rrl current_page_item'
        ,   'title'   => __( 'You are here.', PLUGIN_RRL_TEXT_DOMAIN )
        ,   'charset' => get_bloginfo( 'charset' )
        );

        $Remove_Redundant_Links = new Remove_Redundant_Links(
        // You may hook into the settings with
        // add_filter( 'rrl_settings', 'change_rrl_settings', 10, 1 );
        // where change_rrl_settings( $settings ) returns an altered array.
            apply_filters( 'rrl_settings', $settings )
        );

        ob_start( array ( $Remove_Redundant_Links, 'convert' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'rrl_start', 50 );
```

Comment: Так у вас в строке это написано: `'title'   => __( 'You are here.', PLUGIN_RRL_TEXT_DOMAIN )`. Просто поменяйте `You are here` на нужный title

Comment: Если поменять 'You are here.' например на 'главная', то потом на других страницах где есть удаления цыклической ссылки будет тоже 'главная'. Например страница категорий, страница контакты будет title='главная' , а не "категория" . код  - [фото1](https://nenws.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/cyklicheskaya-ssylka.jpg) , [фото2](https://nenws.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/cyklicheskaya-ssylka-2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`Pashok` имел ввиду заменить строку на вызов функции.

```
'title'   => get_the_title(),
```

Comment: попробую отпишу)

Comment: Вариант сработал, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Правда осле установки этого плагина в pagespeed упло 10 балов 
"Поисковая оптимизация". буду дальше копаться. Вопрос закрыт, еще раз спасибо.